# Android: If Else Android ,Else always activating

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, android-edittext

Hi Im new to android development and this is my first post on stackoverFlow. I am trying to make an in which there is a picture of say brad pitt a edit text and a button. the object is to guess who is in the picture. 
i want it so that if the user types in brad pitt and clicks the button it will bring them onto the second page with a different picture and if incorrect it could do a toast "Wrong Answer".
My problem is that it wont go to the second page when given the right answer.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer);
        final String userinput = input.toString();
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                {if (userinput.equals("tom")) {
                    Intent myintent = new Intent (MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class) ;
                    startActivity (myintent);
                    ;
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    }
                }
            }});
            }           

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are calling input.toString in onCreate - that means you are getting the content of your EditText when the app starts. The user can only type after the onCreate Method is finished because that is when the view is displayed on your phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey you need to declare your `editText` before `onCreate()` and your `String` should not be `final`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText input;
String userinput;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         userinput = input.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), userinput, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            if (userinput.equals("tom")) {
        Intent myintent = new Intent (MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class) ;
        startActivity (myintent);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Answer"+userinput, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    }
});



}
}
```

hey here is the link of my dropbox folder.[link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8xqfl83g63m7bh5/XEevqMDqxA)

Comment: thanks very much guys for helping me. i tried to use all 4 of your answers. i dont know if there contradicting each other. now when i type in tom and click the button the app crashes.

Comment: yes! , Brilliant. Thanks very much everybody for all the help. stackoverflow is absolutely brilliant!. im sorry to say and feel really stupid that when i said the app was crashing it was because i had named the 2nd activity in my manifest the name of my xml instead of the 2nd java class. Thanks very much its been a great learning experince!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `userinput.equals("tom")` do  `"tom".equals(input.getText().toString())`

You do not need `userinput` at all

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of getting the text contained within an EditText is using `EditText.getText()`.  Try replacing this line:

```
final String userinput = input.toString();
```

with something like:

```
final String userinput = input.getText().toString();
```

Also, this should be done after clicking.  Placing this line in onCreate will always set userinput to an empty string or the default value of your EditText, as onCreate only runs at the start of execution.

Answer (score 0):

You only set your `userinput` once, during the onCreate.

`final String userinput = input.toString();`

After that, it is never filled again. But `input.toString()` does not return the actual inputted text. You need `input.getText().toString();` for that.

This means your `userinput` is always empty, as your EditText is probably empty during the start of your activity.
So when you press the button, your `userinput` is still empty, meaning it is not equal to "tom" and thus calling your `else`.

If you want to check if the input is equal to it when you actually press the button, actually fill the `userinput` when the button is pressed. Like so:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           userinput = input.getText().toString();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (userinput.equals("tom")) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent (MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class) ;
                startActivity (myintent);    
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }
        }
```